# Trick 64-bit Ubuntu to allow 32-bit pci wireless card?

Tags: 12.04, 64-bit, 32-bit, ndiswrapper

I have an older 32-bit Belkin F5D6001 (aka ADMtek ADM8211 802.11b Wireless Network Card) that I got to work in 32-bit Ubuntu 12.04 via NDISWrapper (Windows Wireless Networking) by using the CD it originally came with and NDISWrapper (where it said hardware detected: Yes).  Tried the same procedures in 64-bit 12.04 & even though it sees & communicates with the card, it will not connect to Internet.

It can see the networks around me but when I enter the 10-digit (xxxxxxxxxx) security key, it freezes the system.  Did hard reset by powering down & removing plug & power btn for several seconds & restarted but same thing occurs.  Spent countless hours researching on this & was wondering if there is a way to fool this 64-bit OS to accept the driver.  I have tried countless cmds (iwconfig, ip addr, ndiswrapper related, etc.--you name it, I've tried it) and even though it can detect it, it keeps freezing.

I read that there is a default wireless card driver built-in to Ubuntu that may conflict & must be removed in order to prevent the freezing but I'm still a relative novice to Linux & am unsure where this driver is located so I can remove it.  Even if I do find & remove it, I don't think it will solve it because this step was not required in the 32-bit OS which I stated above was successful.  The chipset is ADM8211 with PCIID 1317:8201.

I've tried several drivers I found via SourceForge that indicate it's essentially the same chipset as Realtek 8180 even though its PCIID is different.  Could only find "8180L" drivers on Realtek's website & placed them in Ndiswrapper.  Tried them just in case along with ndiswrapper instructions listed here:

- http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/ndiswrapper/index.php?title=Belkin_F5D6001

to change the PCIID to match the 8180's but to no avail even though was still able to see available networks.  The only conclusions thus far I came to is: 1. that there is no way to make it connect to the web unless there is a way to fool the OS into believing it is a 64-bit capable card or something like that OR 2. the removal of aforementioned default ubuntu driver is definitely required with a 64-bit scenario like I am attempting. If anyone knows of a utility or method for this to occur, please feel free to help.  Thank you and blessings.

Answer (score 1):

You can't run 32-bit kernel mode code with a 64-bit kernel.